How to forward http requests made to local ip address to a cloud url
I have made a Samsung SmartThings Edge driver that runs on the SmartThings Hub. However, the problem is that the hub can only make LAN requests. I want to make a request to the internet, which I can achieve by running a server on the LAN that sends the request on behalf of the hub. But the requirement is such that we cannot run the server on the LAN. Is there a way to forward any request made to http://172.16.0.77:3000/ to https://somecloudapi.com/ from the router itself?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
